# Swift 2.0:Need to display image(PFFile) on PFQueryTableViewController from Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve images(File) from Parse onto a `PFQueryTableViewController`. I've written my code below. I think it's correct but there maybe something small I'm missing. I want to see the images display but I see nothing but blank where the image is supposed to be. Also the image is in Parse. I've tried this instance before and it's worked but for some reason I don't see it working here for this case. So how do I retrieve the images from parse to display on the query?

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Test")

    if let query = profilePage {

        pencil = NSMutableArray()

        query.addAscendingOrder("createdAt")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {               
                for object in objects! {

                    let pencil : PFObject = object as! PFObject
                    self.pencil.addObject(pencil)                 
                }

                let array : NSArray = self.pencil.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects

                self.pencil = NSMutableArray(array: array)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            } else {


            }
        }

    }
}
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell? {
       let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TakerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! TestTaker


        if let uTest : PFObject = self.pencil.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as! PFObject {
        cell.testWriter.text = posts["taker"] as? String
        cell.testInfo.text = posts["information"] as? String
        if let photo = object["picture"] as? PFFile {
        let PFimageV = cell.userImg as PFImageView
        PFimageV.image = UIImage(named: "userImage")
        PFimageV.file = photo
        PFimageV.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.width/2
        PFimageV.clipsToBounds = true
        PFimageV.loadInBackground()

            }

            }
```

Comment: Please include evidence of debugging.  A question like should show readers at minimum that `PFimageV`, and `photo` are correctly initialized.  The question should also contain what you're seeing and what you expect to see ... Is the default image (`"userImage"`) being displayed but not the one in data?  There's a vote-to-close category called "Why is my code not working".  In its current state, this post would qualify.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to fetch an image from Parse using a normal query (you can add your own whereKeys)...

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Your Class Name")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
            for object in objects {
                self.imagesArray.append(UIImage(data: object["image"]!.getData()!)!)

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: I edited my post because I think I already have your method inside my project.

Comment: @JoshyJay Ok cool! Well look at how I append the image into an array. That is how you turn a PFFile into a UIImage.